# Barabasi-Albert model, wrong degree exponent

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph-theory

I'm trying to generate a scale-free network using the Barabasi-Albert model. The model predicts a degree distribution that follows p(k) ~ k^-3 but mine shows k^-2.

[image]

The algorithm was taken from Barabasi's book at this URL: http://barabasi.com/networksciencebook, 
here is the relevant paragraph:

[Barabasi's algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR0IU.png)

Here is my code, could someone please help me figure out what is wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (15,6)

#initialize values
N = 10000
k = 2
m = int(k / 2)

#initialize matrices
adjacency = np.zeros((N,N))
degrees = np.zeros(N)

#add links
for i in range(N):
    degrees[i] = m
    for c in range(m):
        # choose a node with probability proportional to it's degree
        j = np.random.choice(N, p = degrees / (2 * m * i + m + c))
        degrees[j] += 1
        adjacency[i][j] += 1
        adjacency[j][i] += 1


def get_binned_data(labels, values, num):
    min_label, max_label = min(labels), max(labels)
    base = (max_label / min_label) ** (1 / num)
    bins = [base**i for i in range(int(np.log(max_label) / np.log(base)) + 1)]
    binned_values, binned_labels = [], []
    counter = 0
    for b in bins:
        bin_size = 0
        bin_sum = 0
        while counter < len(labels) and labels[counter] <= b:
            bin_size += values[counter]
            bin_sum += values[counter] * labels[counter]
            counter += 1
        if(bin_size):
            binned_values.append(bin_size)
            binned_labels.append(bin_sum / bin_size)
    return binned_labels, binned_values


labels, values = zip(*sorted(Counter(degrees).items(), key = lambda pair: 
pair[0]))

binned_labels, binned_values = get_binned_data(labels, values, 15)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols = 2, nrows = 1)
fig.suptitle('Barabasi-Albert Model',fontsize = 25)

ax1.loglog(binned_labels, binned_values, basex = 10, basey = 10, linestyle = 
'None', marker = 'o',  color = 'red')
ax1.set(xlabel = 'degree', ylabel = '# of nodes')
ax1.set_title('log-log scale (log-binned)',{'fontsize':'15'})

ax2.plot(labels, values, 'ro')
ax2.set(xlabel = 'degree', ylabel = '# of nodes')
ax2.set_title('linear scale',{'fontsize':'15'})

plt.show()
```

Comment: it's not clear to a non-expert: "degree exponent that follows k^-3 but mine shows k^-2."  where?

Comment: edited. Is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not run (probabilities in np.random.choice do not sum to 1). Why not `p = degrees/np.sum(degrees)`?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model), you need to start with some already connected nodes, whereas you start from nothing. Also, you should probably put `degrees[i] = m` after the inner loop to avoid forming links from node i to itself.

This might help, but it's not clear to me how you generate your degree plot, so I can't verify it.

Comment: Well, runs just fine to me. I didn't use sum(degrees) because it's much more expensive to compute compared to calculating me expression, which is the sum of the degrees at the current iteration. Even after switching to the sum method it doesn't seems to work. I implemented me model according to instructions from Barabasi's book. Will edit the post with my code for the plot.